# Qdrant: Which shard is at which node? It seems like all shards are on the same node

Tags: kubernetes, search, kubernetes-helm, distributed, qdrant

I installed qdrant helm chart in cluster with 1 node master, 4 node workers and I created a collection with shard_number=2, replication_factor=2.
When I get cluster info with command:

`curl http://192.168.1.168:31990/collections/test_collection_1/cluster # 6333:31990`

The results is:

```
{
"result":{
"peer_id":7901933018698687,
"shard_count":2,
"local_shards":
{
"shard_id":0,
"points_count":52505,
"state":"Active"
},
{
"shard_id":1,
"points_count":47495,
"state":"Active"
}
,
"remote_shards":

      ],
      "shard_transfers":[
    
      ]

},
"status":"ok",
"time":0.000017769
}
```

1. It's just get info about the number of shards, number of points in each shard, but I want to know which shard is on which node. It seems like all shards are on the same node. And I guess it's because the memory in other nodes not increase and I haven't run 2 command lines:
   `./qdrant --uri 'http://qdrant_node_1:6335/' ./qdrant --bootstrap 'http://qdrant_node_1:6335/'`
   Are these commands run in the container? But how to access container in kubernetes (I tried "kubectl exec -it my-qdrant-demo sh", etc, but error: unable to upgrade connection: pod does not exist?)
   If not, where are these commands run after install qdrant helm chart?
2. Why there is no any remote shard (backup)? Is it relate to pv/pvc ? (I'm using pv with hostPath /home/data in each node)

Comment: To confirm your cluster configuration, what is the output of `GET /cluster`?

Comment: Also: are you sure you've only created this collection when all Qdrant nodes were ready and participating in the cluster? If not, I recommend to recreate the collection. Point counts are only shown for local shards and are an estimate, you should not rely on these.

Comment: I have a cluster with 1 node master and 4 nodes worker. With distributed deployment mode, I want to distribute the Qdrant collection to 2 shards and 2 replicas to backup. So, should I install helm with 1 replica or 4 replicas?

Comment: + With 1 replica, qdrant just install in 1 node, so how to distributed data to other nodes? (I'm using storageClass local-path-storage)
+ With 4 replicas, I tried install many times, but always there is a node which is install qdrant successfully, 3 other nodes are errors:

Comment: `
Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.32.0.2:6333/readyz": dial tcp 10.32.0.2:6333: connect: connection refused
Back-off restarting failed container qdrant in pod qdrant-1_default(aa38bc37-c8e9-40b8-9b43-e739aaa1ba87)
`
Please tell me how should I do?